# Quotient space of $\ell^p$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, quotient-spaces

> Show that
> $$M = \{ x = (x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^p \mid x_{2k} = 0 \ \forall k \in \mathbb{N} \}$$
> is a closed subspace of $\ell^p$. Further, $\text{codim}(M) = \infty$, $\ell^p \cong M$, and $\ell^p / M \cong \ell^p$.

To be very frank, this quest is also available here ([Quotient space of $l^p$ that isometrically isomorphic to $l^p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239686/quotient-space-of-lp-that-isometrically-isomorphic-to-lp)) , but as a beginner I don’t understand the condition that is provided in $M$, I know about $\ell^p$ spaces and understand the idea of isometrically isomorphism. But can’t understand how to proceed?

“I mainly want the proof of the last part, I.e quotient space is isometrically isomorphic to the main space “

I have search a lot to understand and tried to understand from that answered questions but I can’t go any further. So I ultimately decide to ask the question here again.

Thank you for generous  help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't) so that future users with similar questions will have an easier time finding this. In the future you should do the same ^_^

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: can you describe mathematically what you have tried? Have you tried using the definition?

Comment: I was thinking to use this theorem actually,"Every separable Banach space B is isometrically isomorphic to a quotient space of l^1"

Comment: Each element $x=(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)+M\in\ell^p/M$ has a representative $y=(x_0,0,x_2,0,\ldots)+M$, since we can always subtract $(0,x_1,0,x_3,\ldots)\in M$. An isometric isomorphism between $\ell^p/M\to \ell^p$ can be $(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)+M\mapsto (x_0,x_2,x_4,x_6,\ldots)$.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helps a lot.  If possible please give a me a proof of what you said. As a beginner I might wrote it down incorrectly. Sorry I asked a lot.. thank you so much ❤️

Comment: @plop Let $x=\left(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3, \cdots\right)+M\in  l^p/M$ then $y=\left(x_0,0,x_2,0,x_4,0,x_6, \cdots\right)+M\in l^p/M$ such that $x\neq y$. However $T(x)=T(y)$ isn't mean that $T$ is not well defined?